# Access object in UIPageView and UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, pageviews

I have a main`UIViewController` that had `UIScrollView` inside used to be `UIPageView`. so i assign 4 `UIViewControllers` into the `UIPageView`.

when i scroll the page1, it will show no1 `UIViewController` into the `UIScrollView`.

**My problem**
- I want to change the label in controllerA when the user click on the button in pageview1.
- I want to change to next pagedview3 when user click on button pagedview2.

For 1st problem, i had try call the main `UIViewController` from pageview1 but not able to display it.

Comment: Try using 'UIPageViewController' instead of adding viewcontrollers to a scroll view. You can handle the cases easily and reduce code effort. Here's a [link](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) to an example.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr but my main uiviewcontroller is inside of tabbar view controller. is it ok for that?

Comment: That will not be a problem

Comment: @Akhilrajtr i have check the code. the button is inside the page view controller but mine button is one of the page view

Comment: Use delegate or call back from viewcontroller to pagecontroller to notify the button action from viewcontroller to pagecontroller